# Rails Active Record Limited Eager Loading

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, scope, associations, preloading

I have the following (simplified) scenario with Active Record models in Rails 5.0 :

```
class Group
has_many :players

class Player
has_many :attributes

class Attr
attr :name
```

I want to fetch the list of all players belonging to a group with their "pro/amateur" attribute preloaded but without scoping the "attributes" relationship all together (i.e. just preload those attributes but on request provide all "attributes" associate records - unscoped whatsoever)

My first approach is to do:

```
class Player
  scope :with_player_attributes_loaded, ->
   Group.find(1).players.includes(:attr).where(:attr => { :name => "pro/amateur" }.references(:attr))
```

This just **scopes the attributes association itself** instead of **preloading just a subset of this association**.

**OK:**

```
Group.find(1).players.with_player_attributes_loaded
```

1 Group with N players with each player with 1 attribute

**Not OK:**

```
Group.find(1).players.with_player_attributes_loaded.first.attributes
```

does not return all first player's attributes (supposing it has more than 1 in database)

Sorry for the long post. 
How can I achieve preloading of a scoped association but not scope the association itself?

Basically, I want to preload one of the many attributes that is used often but still be able to fetch others on demand.
Thanks!

Comment: using .all, .where() does fetch the unscoped attr association

Comment: i'm 99% sure that this usecase is not covered by rails preloading.

Comment: May want to read this post. https://revs.runtime-revolution.com/conditional-eager-loading-in-rails-9b1c1c592897